# Sorting array(NSString + Number) using NSSortDescriptor in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to sort array using `NSSortDescriptor`.

Here is my code

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"filename"  ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[arrDocuments sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

What I get is this incorrect result.

> 1. New Folder 1
> 2. New Folder 11
> 3. New Folder 12
> 4. New Folder 2

**Expected**

> 1. New Folder 1
> 2. New Folder 2
> 3. New Folder 11
> 4. New Folder 12

Comment: You're using an alphabetic sort. You need an alpha-numeric sort.

Comment: New Folder  is static for every file name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` is an alphabetic search.

You would be better using a function like...

```
compare:options:
```

With the options `NSNumericSearch` this treats any numbers as numeric and so sorts them 1, 2, 10, etc...

alphabetically though 10 comes before 2 hence your problem.

The entire code would look like...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fileName" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

}];

[arrDocuments sortUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

Comment: Great idea works on alpha numeric as well on the only alphabetic or only numeric. good one .thanks !